# Postgres 9.6 export the database structure as pdf

Tags: postgresql, export, erd, postgresql-9.6, database-diagrams

Is there any tool/software the can export all the tables structure (column names , its datatype ) in the database as a pdf/excel/word. additional diagram export will be added advantage.

Comment: http://www.dbschema.com/

Answer (score 6):

You need a [Entity Relation Diagram (ERD)](https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/) generator. The most popular and advanced one that I know of that is FOSS is [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/).

It does everything you want anyway. Though [the diagrams are generated with Graphviz](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/diagramming.html) (so don't expect Visio quality).

You may want to go scavenger hunting through different [graphviz viewers](http://www.graphviz.org/content/resources). This one [using d3](https://github.com/mstefaniuk/graph-viz-d3-js) seems to be pretty decent.